# how handle this error that i am facing when trying to write from SQL to Kudu via Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-kudu

I want to write a huge table from SQL to Kudu Table, I am not able to write it to a Kudu table.

With the following code:

```
kuduDF.write.format('org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu')
              .option('kudu.master',kudu_master)
              .option('kudu.table',"impala::"+kudu_database_name+"."+kudu_table_name).mode('append')
              .option("kudu.operation", operation_type)
              .save()
```

but I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred while calling o202.save.
>   : java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.DefaultSource.createRelation(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode;Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/sources/BaseRelation;

Comment: Well I am not sure either. What do you think the right format is?

Comment: So have you used this format before? When not using kuducontext we wrote thru impala jdbc.

Comment: when I try to read it. Its kind of working with similar format. Its reading the structure but failing to read the data in the table.

Comment: My question was about the write

Comment: Can you use kudu context?

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/How-do-you-connect-to-Kudu-via-PySpark/m-p/66765  Read should be fine

Comment: yup, I referred this link. didn't work for me.I mean its giving same issue

Comment: But you can read?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180302/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-karthik-reddy).

Comment: Resolution evident?

Comment: thank you so much it got resolved. Turns out jar file i was using, was a older version.

Comment: Wow. doc on kudu aspects is quite bad though, I had not seen this version. I will re-install as not at a site with KUDU now.

Comment: thanks i have refere so many book for this

Comment: I guess i am writing a proper blog on this topic. thabks by the way

Answer (score -1):

Can you try with this jar kudu-spark2-tools_2.11.jar . Which jar did you use to make it work